# Access Split DB: Does each user need a separate FE file to run, or can they share a FE file on the network?

Tags: networking, ms-access-2010, frontend

I have read in a few places that each user needs to have their own front-end file when using an access split DB.  Is this true?  If I place a single copy of the front end on the network, and allow each user to open a local instance of that file, will it create conflicts?  Do I really need to put 10 copies of the same file on the network and let each user open his/her own copy?  I am having trouble believing that, though I have seen it mentioned a few times on the web (unless I misinterpreted). Thanks guys!

Comment: The generally accepted practice is for each workstation to have its own copy of the FE. Yes, you can have multiple users sharing a FE found on a server, but you run a higher risk of something getting corrupted.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn You run a ***much*** higher risk of problems. (Almost a certainty, in my experience.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the FE over a network connection will add more bandwidth clutter, too.  You really must deploy the FE to each workstation for the best user experience.

The way we handle it with our current project is to have a copy of the FE on the server that each user downloads.  There's a 'local' version number baked in to the FE app, and a 'latest' version on the BE.  If there's a mismatch detected due to a new version of the FE being deployed, a VB script will download the latest version and replace the one currently on the User's PC (using a batch file).  It's set to do this version check when it first starts up and then periodically while the app is running (with an ability to opt-out if the User's in the middle of some work).

Comment: +1 for your contribution, although I would suggest that "You really should deploy the FE to each workstation" is not strong enough. I maintain that you absolutely **must** ensure that every user is opening their own local copy of the front-end database file. To do otherwise is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys.  You've convinced me.  I like to eliminate as many unknowns as possible, so I won't test my luck.  Local it is, I suppose.  Not my job to manage those workstations anyway, hehe.